# Zoom out Problem on webview in Android 1.6?

Tags: android, webview

In web view, the overview mode method does not works in Android 1.6. Because of the API Level restrictions. is there any possible to show the web view in zoomed out completely? Any Idea?

WebSetting.Zoomdensity is available in API Level 7 only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same situation, you can set your webview initial Scale more or less than 100%

```
myWebView.setInitialScale(50); //0.5x Scale

myWebView.setInitialScale(100); //normal Scale

myWebView.setInitialScale(200); //2x Scale
```